# Add an existing WebPart Using the Sharepoint client object Model

Tags: web-part, client-object-model

My knowledge of the Client Object model is fairly limited, although I have been able to remove and move existing web-parts on a particular page. But I'm now struggling to find and then add a custom web part programmatically using the SharePoint Client Object Model.

The web-part I'm trying to find resides in the Miscellaneous category. I know this by clicking "Page"-->"Edit Page"-->then clicking "Add a Web Part" in one of the zones. Two list boxes appear on the page: one with a heading Categories and another with a heading Web Parts.

So I'm trying to get a web-part in a category named "Miscellaneous" and then I would like to add it to the right hand side of the default.aspx of my sharepoint site.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can do it using Client Object model, to do it, we need the xml file of the webpart you need to add. You can get it by the following method,

**Step 1:** Goto Site settings-> Web part Gallery.

**Step 2:** Then choose the needed web part, click edit -> click view XML -> copy the XML, then put it in the below code.

```
ClientContext clientconteext = newy ClientContext("http://servername/sites/sitename/");
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File page = clientcontext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/Sites/sitename/SitePages/default.aspx");
LimitedWebPartwrtManager lwp= page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);


string webpartxml = /*The webpart XML */;
WebPartDefinition wpd = lwp.ImportWebPart(webpartxml);
wpm.AddWebPart(wpd.WebPart, "Right", 1);
clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Was it not the answer.?

Comment: It was _I'm sure I ticked it a yesterday

Comment: I can't see 'Web Part Gallery' when I look in site settings

Comment: Look for “Web parts”