# Add Webpart to a Page using only Javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-part, client-object-model, csom

Is it possible to add a webpart to a page using Javascript. I want to add a webpart to a specific page whenever a button is clicked.

Comment: Can you put some more specification about what you need?

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps you should execute

1. Get the XML for webpart
2. Load Limited Webpart Manager object
3. Add web part.

You can find details on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185010(v=office.14).aspx#sectionSection1

[Add an existing WebPart Using the Sharepoint client object Model](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79579/add-an-existing-webpart-using-the-sharepoint-client-object-model#)